# Speed up this block of code as much as possible using any resource in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, performance, nested-loops, python-multiprocessing

The following block of code is the content of a function that takes an array of (very large) integers and return a `Boolean`. I would like to make the *runtime* of such a function as small as possible by speeding up the execution as the function needs to be run for many many arrays. What is the most efficient code that can replace this nested `for` loop?

```
flag = 0
for idx, i in enumerate(arr):
    for j in range(idx + 1, len(arr)):
        if i + arr[j] == Number:
            flag = 1
            break
    break
if flag == 0:
    return False
return True
```

**UPDATE: (August 13, 2023) Thanks to Reinderien's Insightful Questions:**

Q: Will this function be called multiple times?

A: Yes. It will be called many many times. The more, the better.

Q: Will either `Number` or `arr` stay the same?

A: No. They both will change; specifically `Number` tend to vary across a very very broad range of integer values while the size of `arr` depends on the magnitude of `Number`

Q: Is `arr` sorted?

A: Yes. In an increasing order.

Q: What is the size of `arr`?

A: It depends on the magnitude of `Number` but in general it is less than `sqrt(N)`

Q: What is a typical value of `Number`?

A: The larger, the better. I want to exhaust the CPU and/or GPU while running this in Kaggle Kernels.

Comment: Will this function be called multiple times? If so, will either `Number` or `arr` stay the same? Is `arr` sorted? What is the size of `arr`? What is a typical value of `Number`? The answer to these questions will make or break a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solution has a time complexity of O(n), which is much faster compared to the nested loop approach.

Replace your existing code with the has_pair_with_sum function and call it with your array and target number. This should significantly speed up the execution for large arrays.

```
def has_pair_with_sum(arr, target_sum):
    """
    Checks if there is a pair of distinct elements in the array
    'arr' that adds up to the 'target_sum'.

    Args:
        arr (list): List of integers to search for a pair.
        target_sum (int): The desired sum to find.

    Returns:
        bool: True if a pair with the target sum exists, False otherwise.
    """
    seen_numbers = set()  # Set to store seen numbers
    for num in arr:
        complement = target_sum - num
        if complement in seen_numbers:
            return True  # Found a pair that adds up to the target sum
        seen_numbers.add(num)
    return False  # No such pair was found

# Example call
input_array = [3, 5, 9, 2, 8]
target = 11
result = has_pair_with_sum(input_array, target)
print(f"Pair with sum {target} exists: {result}")
```

Comment: Would you please make it more readable?